# Passing String From datagridview to textbox in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have set up a 2 forms one loads up a datagridview and the user clicks on the view to select the value they want. I can get the value displaying inside a messagebox on the same form as the datagridview However when i try to pass it across to another form it appears NULL. How would i get it displaying inside the textbox. Here is my code. When i debug the code it first passes across the value correctly but when it finishes running it shows as a null value. I have tried a number of different ways of doing this tried to do it using public variables on the different classes also.

Form one with the TextBox

```
 public void FillTextBoxes(object sender, EventArgs e, string SupplierID)
    {
        supplierVO _SupplierVo = new supplierVO();
        ListOfSuppliers _ListOfSuppliers = new ListOfSuppliers();
        SupplierID = _ListOfSuppliers.SupplierCode;                                   
        MessageBox.Show(SupplierID);
        txtSupplierCode.Text = SupplierID;         
    }
```

Form2 with the dataGridView

```
       // Links to the user double click of the datagrid
    public void SelectGridInformation (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        ChangeSupplierInfo _ChangeSupplerInfo = new ChangeSupplierInfo();

        supplierVO _SupplierVO = new supplierVO();

        Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

        string SelectedSupplierID = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();

        SupplierCode = SelectedSupplierID;

        _SupplierVO.SupplierCode = SelectedSupplierID;

        _ChangeSupplerInfo.FillTextBoxes(sender, e, SelectedSupplierID);

        this.Close();
    }
```

I have been trying to do this with the Get and Set Property's here is the code sample for this.

```
 public string SupplierCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _SupplierCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _SupplierCode = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess would be that you would want to use an existing instance of your `ListOfSuppliers` class instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: Best way is to decouple the functionality by using some sort of messaging implementation then use the publisher / subscriber model.

Comment: Where in code you put `FillTextBoxes` function?

Comment: @Fabio its on the Form that i am looking to pass the variable across too.

Comment: ok, but where inside of Form_Load or in constructor?

Comment: If `MessageBox.Show(SupplierID)` show right value, then `txtSupplierCode.Text` must overwrited somewheres after your code maybe

Comment: Im thinking it might be because on the second form i have  supplierVO _SupplierVo = new supplierVO(); thus creating a new instance and not using the previous instance on the other form. Anyone any ideas how i would access the previous instance to be able to access the get set properties.

Comment: If you want access from Form2 your inctance of supplierVO created in Form1, then just put it in constructor of Form2(like in my answer, but parameter will be reference of instance supplierVO) then do what you want with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if we're thinking about the same thing, but check this out.
You've got Form1 where's DataGridView and Form2 where's your TextBox.

So let's create Form2 inside Form1...

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.show();
```

... and get DataGridView's selected cell

```
form2.value = getDataGridValue();
```

Then, let's declare property inside Form2, to which we'll be passing value selected by user.

```
private string _value;

public string value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
      _value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(_value);
    }
}
```

Notice that we're using INotifyPropertyChanged so include this declaration inside Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Create public event

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

And raise it wherever our user clicks something in DataGridView

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string value)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
```

Then on Form2Load subscribe to your new event

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Form2_PropertyChanged);
}
```

And do the stuff

```
void Form2_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   this.InvokeIfRequired((value) => textBox1.Text = value, e.PropertyName);
}
```

For me it works fine, I'm selecting value in DataGridView on Form1 and getting this value inside TextBox on Form2, but as I said, I'm not sure if we're thinking about the same thing...

Comment: Thanks for the reply just a bit confused see he create a public event do i need to that on form1 the form with the datagrid?

Comment: Form1 = form with a dataGrid, Form2 = form with a TextBox, you're creating public event on form2. On Form1 you just have to initialize form2, pass user selection to it and show it. Everything else (properties, events) is on form2.

Comment: [Here's a working example if you're still interested](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/96085825/suplier.zip)

Comment: Thanks sorry for the late reply. When i run that i get a error out of range. The e.ColumnIndex alue is -1 no matter what cell i click on. think this is the reason for the error any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1):

if you need only string SupplierID in your Form2
then create a variable of supplierID in Form2

```
private String supplierID;
```

independ on purpose of this data create a properties for this variable

then create a new custom constructor for Form2

```
public void Form2(String supplierid)
{
    this.supplierID = supplierid;
}
```

in Form1 when you create instance of Form2 just use your custom constructor

```
//somwhere in Form1
Form2 frm2 = New Form2(SelectedSupllierID)
frm2.ShowDialog() //…
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line in this code is your issue.

```
public void FillTextBoxes(object sender, EventArgs e, string SupplierID)
{
    supplierVO _SupplierVo = new supplierVO();
    ListOfSuppliers _ListOfSuppliers = new ListOfSuppliers();
    SupplierID = _ListOfSuppliers.SupplierCode;   //This line is the problem.                                
    MessageBox.Show(SupplierID);
    txtSupplierCode.Text = SupplierID;         
}
```

You are getting the SupplierID from the parameters of the method. Why are you updating the SupplierID with empty value. When you create a new object of ListOfSuppliers, then the SupplierCode in that class is empty and you are assigning an empty value to your SupplierID.

Also I can't see the purpose of the variable _ListOfSuppliers???

Comment: When i was testing it i passed a variable across to see if i could get it working that way but had no joy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the `string` by creating Form `New Instance` by some reason

try this one.. in your `Form1` try to show the Form2 by this code.

```
 using (var f = new Form2
                        {
                            Owner = this
                        }) f.ShowDialog();
```

then in `Form2` event, it should be like this

```
    Form1 f0 = this.Owner as Form1; //_ChangeSupplerInfo 

    supplierVO _SupplierVO = new supplierVO();

    Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

    string SelectedSupplierID = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();

    //SupplierCode = SelectedSupplierID;

    //_SupplierVO.SupplierCode = SelectedSupplierID;

    f0.FillTextBoxes(SelectedSupplierID);

    this.Close();
```

and from `Form1`

```
 public void FillTextBoxes(string SupplierID)
    {
        supplierVO _SupplierVo = new supplierVO();
        ListOfSuppliers _ListOfSuppliers = new ListOfSuppliers();
        //SupplierID = _ListOfSuppliers.SupplierCode;                                   
        MessageBox.Show(SupplierID);
        txtSupplierCode.Text = SupplierID;         
    }
```