# display the value of datagridview in the textboxes present in another form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

how can we use the same data grid values in two different forms?

i have a grid view which displays the list of buses and their starting location and destination and the trip date time..

and also have a user home page where the user books the seats and in the user page i have to display the contents of the previously mentioned data grid view

i used the code

```
    public static string SetValueForText1 = "";
    public static string SetValueForText2 = "";
    public static string SetValueForText3 = "";
    public static string SetValueForText4 = "";
    public static string SetValueForText13 = "";
```

and

```
        int i = gv_bus.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        SetValueForText16 = gv_bus.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        SetValueForText1 = gv_bus.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        SetValueForText2 = gv_bus.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        SetValueForText3 = gv_bus.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        SetValueForText4 = gv_bus.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

and in the user home page i have used this code

```
        lbl_startng1.Text =BUS_BOOKING.BUS_PAGE.SetValueForText1;
        lbl_destination1.Text = BUS_BOOKING.BUS_PAGE.SetValueForText2;
        lbl_trip1.Text = BUS_BOOKING.BUS_PAGE.SetValueForText3;
        lbl_dur1.Text = BUS_BOOKING.BUS_PAGE.SetValueForText4;
        lbl_no1.Text = BUS_BOOKING.BUS_PAGE.SetValueForText13;
```

but this is not working since the user page loads when we debug and it displays empty labels

anyone please help. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this and plenty of examples on this site.

[Example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974510/passing-string-from-datagridview-to-textbox-in-another-form?rq=1)

I would go with using custom events and have your second form subscribe to events on your first form.

You could expose properties on your second form and update from your first form.

I would investigate the first option as it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This is just theory, but cant you simply pass the datasource object to the second form via the constructor of the second form??